# Each Node in the Queue Contains the Same Data

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, nodes

These are the struct definitions for the queue and request nodes

```
typedef struct request{
  struct request * next;
  int valid;
  int request_id;
  int check_acc_id;
  struct transfer * transfers;
  int num_transfers;
  struct timeval starttime, endtime;
}request;

typedef struct queue{
  struct request * head;
  struct request * tail;
  int num_jobs;
}queue;
```

This is the function to initialize the queue

```
queue * createQueue(){
  queue *que = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue)); 
  que->num_jobs = 0;
  que->head = NULL;
  que->tail = NULL;

  return queue;
}
```

In my main, I run a continuous loop to get user input. There are 3 different request the user can make.

```
int reqid = 1;
queue *que = createQueue();

char * command = malloc(200);

while(1){
    printf("> ");
    fgets(command, 200, stdin);
    fixEnd(command);
    
    reqid += runCommand(command, reqid, que);
            
    /*if(req.valid == 1){
        reqid = addToQueue(&req, que);      
    }*/
    
    printReqInfo(que);
}

return 0;
```

The user input is sent to the runCommand function to determine what request was made and create a request node based on that.

```
int runCommand(char * command, int request_id, queue * que){

  struct timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
  int reqID = request_id;

  request r;
  r.request_id = reqID;
  r.valid = 1;
  r.check_acc_id = 0;
  r.next = (request*)malloc(sizeof(request));
  r.transfers = (transfer*)malloc(sizeof(transfer) * 10);
  r.num_transfers = 0;
  r.starttime = time;

  char * req = malloc(200);
  char * token = malloc(20);
  token = strtok(command, " ");
  strcpy(req, token);

  if(strcmp(req, "CHECK") == 0){
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    int id = atoi(token);
    
    r.check_acc_id = id;
    
    return addToQueue(&r, queue);   
  }

  else if(strcmp(req, "TRANS") == 0){
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    int count = 0;
    
    while(token != NULL){
        transfer t;
        t.acc_id = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        t.amount = atoi(token);
        
        r.transfers[count] = t;
        
        ++count;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
    r.num_transfers = count;
    
    return addToQueue(&r, queue);   
  }

  else if(strcmp(req, "END") == 0){
    printf("Exiting Process\n");
    free_accounts();
    exit(0);
  }
        
  else{
    printf("Request Invalid: %s\n", command);
    r.valid = 0;
    return 0;
  }
    
}
```

If a 'CHECK' or 'TRANS' request is made the request node is meant to be added to the queue, if the user makes a request 'END', the program will just exit.

This is the function to add the request node to the queue

```
int addToQueue(request *req, queue * que){
  //pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);

  if(que == NULL || req == NULL){
    printf("Request Not Added\n");
    return 0;
  }

  if(que->num_jobs > 0){
    if(que->tail == NULL){
        que->tail = req;
        que->head->next = req;
    }
    else{
        que->tail->next = req;
        que->tail = req;
    }
  }

  else{
    que->head = req;
    que->tail = NULL;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&empty);
  }

  que->num_jobs += 1;
  int x = req->request_id;

  //pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);

  printf("< ID %d\n", x);
  return 1;

}
```

The issue I'm having is that each request node is the same. The first input request is handled correctly and that request is added as the head of the queue. When I input a second request, the request node is added, but the head is also changed to the same data as the new input. When a third request is made, all three request node's data values are equal to whatever the newest request was.

For example, if I input the following:

CHECK 1
CHECK 2
TRANS 5 100

When I print the data from each request node in the queue it SHOULD look like this:

ID: 1 CHECK: 1
ID: 2 CHECK 2
ID: 3
ACC: 5 AMT: 100

Where ID is the request id, starting with 1 and incrementing with each request, and CHECK is the account that's balance is to be checked. With a trans request, ACC is the account to make a transaction and AMT is the dollar amount to be deposited/withdrawn. Note the specific information about the accounts is not really relevant to the problem, I just explained it so there wouldn't be confusion of where they came from.

However, when I run the program with that input, the output is coming out like so:

ID: 3
ACC: 5 AMT: 100
ID: 3
ACC: 5 AMT: 100
ID: 3
ACC: 5 AMT: 100

If I then make another request, say CHECK 8, the output changes to

ID: 4 CHECK: 8
ID: 4 CHECK: 8
ID: 4 CHECK: 8
ID: 4 CHECK: 8

Comment: Please do not provide code as images. Include the code as text and format it (use toolbar).

Comment: Sorry, first time posting on here

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check all your code (there are several unresolved dependencies, and a mistake in the spelling of `que` versus `queue`), but the problem you describe is the consequence of defining `r` as a local (stack) allocated structure. Each time you call `runCommand`, `&r` will be the *same* memory address, and that memory is automatically freed each time `runCommand` returns.

Yet, you want each call of `runCommand` to create a request that is separate and can be used and referenced outside of `runCommand`.

So instead use `malloc` to allocate memory for a request.